# SQL Server 2012 multiple joins technique

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have appended a series of columns (11 of them) to the end my data that each act as a flag.

Here is a sample of these categories:
(Notice that multiple flags can appear for a single row!)

```
cat2    cat3    cat4    cat5    cat6    cat7    cat8    cat9    cat10   cat11   cat12
NULL    1       NULL    NULL       2    NULL    NULL       1    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL       2    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL       1       1    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL       1       1    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
   3    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL       2    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I have a separate table that pairs each flag with a description string.

```
ref_id  category_position   description
------------------------------------------------
1                      2    string description 1
2                      2    string description 2
3                      2    string description 3
1                      3    string description 4
1                      4    string description 5
1                      5    string description 6
1                      6    string description 7
2                      6    string description 8
1                      7    string description 9
1                      8    string description 10
2                      8    string description 11
1                      9    string description 12
1                      10   string description 13
1                      11   string description 14
1                      12   string description 15
```

I want to somehow join my string description against every category that is not null, so that my categories are 'human readable' and defined.

Here is a possible outcome that would be acceptable to me, based on the first row of sample data (including the header):

```
cat3  [join description]     cat6  [join description]     cat9  [join description]
   1  string description 4      2  string description 8      1  string description 12
```

Trouble is - I don't know how to do this multi-part join. I don't want to join 12 times as this seems sloppy and perhaps won't work for the millions of rows I'm operating on.

Comment: This is a terrible table design.  Normalize your data.

Comment: You can join to your table a bunch of times, or use a function to return the value based on your ref_id. Taxing....

Comment: The data comes in raw/live, and I am categorizing various aspects of the data to include in a summary.  Normalization isn't an option because it's raw telecom data.

Comment: You'll have to join 12 times. It's a small table that you are joining to, so it's not unreasonable. Perhaps rethinking your schema will yield a better long-term answer, but given your requirements I think you're stuck between a rock (hard coded fields for each cat) and a hard place (EAV anti-pattern). The crummy part of the multi-join is that you have to subquery that table to get only results for your category. But... again it's small, so it's probably not huge overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function alternative... which isn't going to be faster than doing the joins but is useful in limited use.

```
create function dbo.returnDesc (@ref_id int)
returns varchar (256)
as
begin
    declare @return varchar(256)

    set @return = (select [description] from yourTable where ref_id = @ref_id)

    return @return
end
```

Then in use....

```
select
   ....
   dbo.returnDesc(cat2),
   dbo.returnDesc(cat3),
   dbo.returnDesc(cat4),
   ....
from
    YourMainTable
```